# Order of embedded files in a PDF Portfolio file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am successfully extracting the contents of a PDF Portfolio file using code similar to this:

```
internal void ExtractAttachments(string file_name, string folderName) {
    PdfDictionary documentNames = null;
    PdfDictionary embeddedFiles = null;
    PdfDictionary fileArray = null;
    PdfDictionary file = null;
    PRStream stream = null;

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file_name)) {
        PdfDictionary catalog = reader.Catalog;

        documentNames = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(catalog.Get(PdfName.NAMES));

        if (documentNames != null) {
            embeddedFiles = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(documentNames.Get(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES));
            if (embeddedFiles != null) {
                PdfArray filespecs = embeddedFiles.GetAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);

                for (int i = 0; i < filespecs.Size; i++) {
                    i++;
                    fileArray = filespecs.GetAsDict(i);
                    file = fileArray.GetAsDict(PdfName.EF);

                    foreach (PdfName key in file.Keys) {
                        stream = (PRStream)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(file.GetAsIndirectObject(key));
                        string attachedFileName = fileArray.GetAsString(key).ToString();
                        byte[] attachedFileBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);

                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderName, attachedFileName), attachedFileBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I've noticed that these component files are extracted in an order different than they're displayed in the original PDF using Adobe Reader XI.  The display order of these component files is apparently given in an "Index" property, which you can show in the Reader UI by selecting to view a Portfolio file in Files mode (as opposed to Layout mode), right clicking any component file and selecting 'View' > 'Index' from the context menu.

My question: how can I find this 'index' property before extracting files from a PDF Portfolio file?

Comment: Apparently I can't edit tags on my own question; perhaps someone will be kind enough to remove the [itext] tag and add the [itextsharp] tag?

Comment: The itext and itextsharp tags are synonymous, because they both describe exactly the same API, one implemented in Java and the other in C#.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I understand that but I figured since my code snippet is C# and I'm actually looking for a .NET solution I figured itextsharp would be the more appropriate tag for future searchers.  I'd love to see Java/iText solutions of course!

Comment: Since you have appropriately tagged your question with `itext` AND `c#`, your answers will most definitely NOT be in Java. :) The reasons why the `itext` and `itextsharp` tags were merged: a) answered by mostly the same people, so they have less tags to monitor b) answers to iText questions are mostly language-agnostic and are valid for Java as well as C#.

Answer (score 0):

The "Index" property may or may not be the actual piece of metadata that the Portfolio is sorted on. Portfolios can be sorted on any number of the collection fields including hidden ones. To find the actual sort order, You need to get the "Sort" dictionary out of the "Collection" dictionary in the "Catalog". Once you have that, you can sort the files based on the "CI" (Collection Info) Dictionary in each of the attachments.

I'd throw some code your way but I don't use iText... Sharp or otherwise.